# mysql: create a "userstamp"

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to have automatic "userstamps" in my DB. Meaning, everytime a user changes something, his Userid is written into a column. 
I tried to solve this by using an "After update" trigger, but my code does not work:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`tantworten_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `tantworten` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
Insert into tantworten (User)
Values (current_user());
END
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it. The answer from Jean Doux was nearly correct (Thanks!). MySQL cannot update the same table, where the trigger is issued with AFTER UPDATE.
Therefore I just set the trigger to BEFORE UPDATE.

I hope this helps someone else too:

```
create trigger userupdate Before Update on tantworten 
FOR EACH ROW
set New.User = current_user();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this (I can't test it right now) :

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db`.`tantworten_AFTER_UPDATE` 
BEFORE UPDATE ON `tantworten` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.User = current_user();
END
```

Comment: I tried the following now (your code only gave the error: Unknown variable):

`create trigger userupdate After Update on tantworten 
 FOR EACH ROW
 Insert Into tantworten(User)
 Select current_user();`


Altough this creates the trigger, I cannot change anything now:
Error:

´1442: Can't update table 'tantworten' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.